# Angular 2 deleting of selected item of an array in Child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of elements and each array item has one Delete link on click of which I want the selected array item to be deleted. I am pushing the objects into the array already and able to get the data.

The code I am using is mentioned below.

Child Component-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{element.name}}
      <span (click)="deleteElement()">Delete</span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input()
  element: any;
  @Output()
  elementDeleted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  deleteElement() {
    this.elementDeleted.emit();
  }
}
```

My Parent component-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <child *ngFor="let element of elements; let i= index;" [element]="element" (elementDeleted)="onElementDeleted(element)">
      </child>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.elements = [
      { name: 'element1' },
      { name: 'element2' },
      (...)
    ];
  }

  onElementDeleted(element) {
    var index = this.elements.findIndex((elt) => (elt===element));
    if (index != -1) {
      this.elements.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Right now, every time the last item of the array is getting deleted instead of deleting the selected item.For ex. If i click on  Delete link for the 0th or 1st index, still the last item is being deleted. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: well, you can also do it this way:

You need to pass which element is to be deleted, so that the right element will be deleted. So change your code a bit, below pass the element in your delete.

```
<div>
  {{element.name}}
  <span (click)="deleteElement(element)">Delete</span> 
</div>
```

and make your emit pass the element to be deleted:

```
deleteElement(element) {
  this.elementDeleted.emit(element);
}
```

and then delete the element:

```
onElementDeleted(element) {
  let index = this.elements.indexOf(element);
  this.elements.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And as mentioned by Daniel, `#` is deprecated, use `let` instead.

Comment: I was also looking at this and I can say that the flow is correct and works this way: `(click)="deleteElement()"` -> `this.elementDeleted.emit()` -> `(elementDeleted)="onElementDeleted(element)"`, so that's definitely not this problem.

Comment: Yaah, I just didn't mention the `#` in my answer :D I didn't even think of doing it another way than this, well, now there is two options. Didn't think that # and let would matter, and that # would still be supported, apparently not :)

Comment: There were probably too many problems (like this one up) with the template global-scoped `#` used in `*ngFor` and it has been removed, using it now throws an error.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tested it and found out to be so :)

Comment: I am thinking if the another variable i which i am declaring in *ngFor is creating problem.updated my code a bit.

Comment: @techiequestie Adding `index` in the iteration does not affect the behavior. Besides using the wrong selector in parent (must be a typo, otherwise your code wouldn't run), your code is fully working! :) It is tested both by me and Daniel who has provided a plunker for you with your code. So your problem has to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your Angular2 version. The problem here is probably with the removed syntax `*ngFor=#element of elements`, where the `#element` is changing after assignments, so you get the last element from the list in every case (template global scope). New syntax is `*ngFor="let element of elements"` and it works fine.
Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/OsxUS3V5pB3Tqko5SojJ?p=preview

Comment: +1 Your answer is definitely more on point when it comes to question, but I figure I'll leave my answer here just for a different perspective if not anything else :P

Comment: changed # to let still facing the same issue.

Comment: Which A2 version do you use?

Comment: @angular/compiler-cli : 2.3.1 as per my  package json